# Confused about 'staircases'

Tags: education

Hi I'm currently reading a paper, which contains an experiment I was to re-create - is there any chance someone can explain the staircase to me?

I've had a quick Google - and I haven't really got anywhere - I'm not even sure if this falls under mathematics, if I'm honest. I've tried to break up the text a little, but I'm still super lost on this.

I can reword the question if the detail of the article is unhelpful - I just didn't want to remove something that was actually of importance

> ... In each trial, one eye was presented with a population of “signal”
> dots that all moved in the same direction (left or right).
>
> The other eye was presented with the noise dots that moved in random directions.
>
> The task was to indicate the motion direction of the signal dots. **To
> measure the threshold number of signal dots required for 79% correct
> performance (the motion coherence threshold), the number of signal
> dots was varied on a trial-by-trial basis in a three-down, one-up
> staircase procedure with a proportional step size of 50% before the
> first reversal and 25% thereafter.**
>
> **The starting point for each staircase was 100 signal dots and 0 noise dots.**
>
> When dots were removed from the signal population, they were added to the noise population and vice versa.
>
> **Each staircase consisted of six reversals, and the
> last five reversals were averaged to estimate threshold. During each
> threshold measurement, two staircases were randomly interleaved.**
>
> One staircase measured the motion coherence threshold when the signal dots
> were presented to the left eye and the other staircase measured the
> motion coherence threshold when signal dots were presented to the
> right eye.
>
> In each case, the eye that did not see the signal dots saw
> the noise dots.
>
> By randomly interleaving the staircases, participants
> could not tell which eye had seen the signal and which had seen the
> noise as the stimuli were fused. The interleaved staircase
> measurements lasted approximately 3 minutes ...

Anyone that has any advice or pointers are greatly welcomed :)
Thanks!

---

100 - 3 down, 1 up - Proportional step size of 50% before the first reversal
and 25% thereafter.

1. 100 > right > right > right >  50 > wrong - is then 75?
2. 100 > right > right > right >  50 > right > right> right> 25 > wrong - is then 31.25?

Is this how this works? Is the 25% proportional to the current, or the max?

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychophysics#Staircase_procedures

Comment: I saw the wiki and wasn't 100% sure I was on the right track - I think I get it now, the wording has really thrown me :)

Thanks!


100 - 3 down, 1 up
100 > r